# ColdFusion - Web Server - Directory Serving - IIS

Tags: iis, coldfusion, iis-8, coldfusion-2016

Not sure if this is controlled in ColdFusion Application.cfm in root directory or through the IIS webserver.

But I am trying to setup multiple subsites off of 1 Root Website using the same ColdFusion code, then setting a distinct data source by sniffing the URL ie: [www.root.com/bob](http://www.root.com/bob) and using cgi.http_host.

So I can use the same code and different URL such as:

```
      www.root.com
      www.root1.com
      www.root2.com
```

But I need to setup a separate site each time in the webserver (that is fine and understood).

But I would like to run the same code on same root website but on a subdirectory.
So I'd like to run:

```
      www.root.com/test
      www.root.com/test2
      www.root.com/test3
      www.root.com/newsignup
```

And all these subdirectories can then run the same code, without having to setup multiple websites in IIS.

Is this easily done using ColdFusion? or is it all IIS mapping?

Comment: The part about having a datasource depend on a cgi variable can easily be accomplished in your application file.  Having every site run the exact same code sounds tricky but you appear to have that part figured out.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is located somewhere like

```
E:\path\to\wwwroot
```

In IIS, you have a site setup with that folder as web root. That site has a primary domain

```
www.someDomain.com
```

Then you want to serve the same code under different domains:

- [www.anotherDomain.com](http://www.anotherDomain.com)
- myCFsite.someExistingSite.com
- myCFsite.anotherExistingSite.com
- [www.YetAnotherDomain.com](http://www.YetAnotherDomain.com)

In IIS, you'll have to set these up as domain aliases for your site. Look for "Bindings" in IIS Manager. You can also do this by editing the `website.config` file that will be created in your web root.

If you need different settings to be loaded per domain, you'll have to update your application. I usually set up database tables that map a list of those domains to their settings. That way you can lookup by `cgi.http_host` to find and cache settings.

```
<cfif !structKeyExists(application.settings, cgi.http_host)>
    <!--- Look up settings, then cache them here. --->
    <cfset application.settings[cgi.http_host] = ...>
</cfif>
```

Now you can reference settings per domain throughout the same code base.

Comment: It's same domain but subdirectories.

So.. yes www.somedomain.com is main code.

But same code on..
www.somedomain/bob
www.somedomain/Carl
www.somedomain.com/Fred

Comment: Use a URL rewrite in IIS then. So don't create those subdirectories, instead add a rewrite rule for each one pointing to the root, and passing a parameter which you can check for in the CF code to see which path was originally requested.